# Can't get entry of persistent room in ofMucRoom table in c#.net using agsxmpp

Tags: c#, agsxmpp, muc

I am developing chat application using agsxmpp in c#.net,currently i managed to create the persistent room on openfire server,whose entry is shown in openfire server.but the problem is i can't get the same entry of room in openfire mysql database until,i manually edit the room in openfire.here,i am posting my code of creating persistent room,is there any way to get the entry of persistent room in both openfire server and openfire mysql database,almost concurrently,without doing manually edit into room entry of openfire server?please help,if you know anythig related to this...

```
            Jid room = new Jid(textBox1.Text + "@conference.myopenfireservername");               
             xmpp.MessageGrabber.Add(room,
                                  new BareJidComparer(),
                                 new MessageCB(MessageCallBack),
                                  null);


            Jid owner = new Jid(u_id+"@myopenfireservername");
            xmpp.SendMyPresence();

            MucManager muc = new MucManager(xmpp);              
            muc.JoinRoom(room,GlobalVar.my_perm_nm);
            muc.AcceptDefaultConfiguration(room);
            xmpp.SendMyPresence();
            muc.GrantAdminPrivileges(room, owner);
            muc.GrantOwnershipPrivileges(room, owner);
            muc.GrantMembership(room, owner);              
            Jid membs;
            for (int i = 0; i < members_id.Count; i++)
            {
                membs =new Jid( members_id[i].ToString() + "@myopenfireservername");
                muc.Invite(membs, room);
                muc.GrantMembership(room, membs);
               // muc.Invite(roomy, room);
            }              


                MessageBox.Show("Your group has been created..", "Congratulations", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);//displaying this messagebox after creating room and also entry in openfire server,but can't get in mysql database
```

Answer (score 0):

got the answer!!created romm with configurations instead of acepting defult configuration.than once the room created than do the rest of stuff.the link for which i found very usefull,
http://forum.ag-software.net/thread/1787-muc-invitation-to-join,
hope this helps someone!!!